# Alexa API call is not returning anything

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

Hello and good evening all!

I have setup an API call in my Alexa app and I'm trying to get a basic understanding of why it isn't working with the URL/response I have.

I know the API call works because when I replace 'host' with 'api.icndb.com' and 'path' with '/jokes/random' it works (when I access the response data using response.value.quote).

My API call will not work with the URL I have provided or maybe perhaps it's the way I'm trying to access the data.
The API provides data in an array with objects nested inside of it which is different from the aforementioned URL.

To see what I'm referring to, here is the URL for the sample Alexa skill that I built my app from with the 'api.icndb.com' API I'm referring to.

Here is my code:

```
/* eslint-disable  func-names */
/* eslint-disable  no-console */

const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');
var https = require('https')


const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
   const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
   return request.type === 'LaunchRequest'
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('Welcome to Simpson Speak')
      .getResponse();
  }
};


const GetQuoteHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'GetQuote';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
     const response = await httpGet();

     console.log(response);

     return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(response[0].author)
      .getResponse()

  }
};

function httpGet(){
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
      host: 'thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me',
      port: 443,
      path: '/quotes',
      method: 'GET',
    };
    const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      let returnData = '';

      response.on('data', (chunk)=>{
        returnData += chunk;
      });
      response.on('end',()=>{
        resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
      });
      response.on('error', (error)=>{
        reject(error);
      });
    });
    request.end();
  }));
};

const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.standard();

exports.handler = skillBuilder
  .addRequestHandlers(
    LaunchRequestHandler,
    GetQuoteHandler
  )
  .lambda();
```

Comment: the code seems to work just fine as I just tested it. This is the response `[{"quote":"I believe the children are the future... Unless we stop them now!","character":"Homer Simpson","image":"https://cdn.glitch.com/3c3ffadc-3406-4440-bb95-d40ec8fcde72%2FHomerSimpson.png?1497567511939","characterDirection":"Right"}]` I get.

what error are you getting? Maybe it's not activating the GetQuoteHandler?

Comment: @balsimpson I am literally getting "null" in my JSON output and in the simulator Alexa is saying "there was a problem with the requested skill's response"

Comment: @balsimpson (this is so ironic by the way) when I text my skill in the simulator using the phrase "tell simpson speak to give me a simpsons quote" it returns an error

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @balsimpson "there was a problem with the requested skill's response"

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what i get @balsimpson https://imgur.com/a/syBCo4B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work with your httpGet function.

```
const GetQuoteHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'GetQuote';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const {responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
        const response = await httpGet();
        console.log(response);
        const items = response[0]
        const item = items.quote

        var speechText = "Your quote is" + JSON.stringify(item)

        return responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .reprompt("don't even know that one")
          .getResponse();
      }
}
```

Comment: This was correct but I'm confused as to why this worked but mines did not?

Comment: The two items that caused your errors: .speak(response[0].author) resulted in errors, My approach was to take the quote array and then isolate the quote. The other issue was without JSON. stringify your data objects were returning Object.object first with your code then object in the isolated version. Glad to help.